# Display / hide button when I select image

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an input that allows me to select multiple images, when it is empty the button appears, when I select an image is there any way to overlay the button? That is, when the box is empty, we see the button, but when an image is inserted in the box is it possible to make this button not visible? I have tried with z-index and javascript, but it did not work correctly.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euimfb)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="drop">
      <div class="cont">
        <div class="browse">
            Upload files
          </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Click to upload or drop your files
        </div>       
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="urls.length > 0">
          <img [src]="urls[0]"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(urls[0])">X</span>
        </ng-container>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drop {
  margin-left: 32px;
    width: 928px;
  height: 696px;
    border: 3px dashed #DADFE3;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    /* margin: auto; */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  /*&:hover
    cursor: pointer
    background: #f5f5f5*/;
}

.drop .cont {
    width: 500px;
    height: 170px;
    color: #8E99A5;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.drop .cont i {
    font-size: 400%;
    color: #8E99A5;
    position: relative;
}

.drop .cont .desc {
    text-align: center;
   font: Regular 16px/19px Montserrat;
   letter-spacing: 0;
   color: #4981C2;
}

.drop .cont .browse {
    margin: 10px 25%;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: #ECF2F9;
    text-align: center;
font: Bold 13px/20px Noto Sans;
letter-spacing: 0;
color: #4D4F5C;
}

.drop input {
  width: 928px;
  height: 650px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#list {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#list .thumb {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #323a44;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}

img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use ngIf on your button if the images are visible?

```
      <div class="cont" *ngIf="urls.length === 0">
        <div class="browse" >
            Upload files
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Click to upload or drop your files
        </div>       
      </div>
```

Comment: This should be better solution than shadowman_93. Your code can use multiply images, so your urls.length will be more than 1 or less than 1. If you add 2 images the button will be shown again.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want display the upload button when images are selected you can do some like this:

```html
<div class="drop">
     <div class="cont">
        <div class="browse">
            Upload files
          </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Click to upload or drop your files
        </div>       
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="urls.length > 0; else drag">
          <img [src]="urls[0]"><span class="delete" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(urls[0])">X</span>
        </ng-container>
       <ng-template #drag>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
      </ng-template>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this piece of code for selected file check,

```
*ngIf="urls && urls.length != 1"
```

Actually for your example,

```
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="browse"  *ngIf="urls && urls.length != 1">
        Upload files
      </div>
    <div class="desc">
      Click to upload or drop your files
    </div>       
  </div>
```

Means that hide my upload button when my urls array's lenght not different from 1.